# Why images display so slow?

Tags: android, xml

Hi I'm using many ImageViews in my application and SoundPool. Is there any possibility to optimize it, cause as far as I know apk has already compressed pngs but id doesnt do anythink. I've added an`droid:largeHeap="true"` but it also didnt help.

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476155/the-png-loading-get-out-of-memory-android/29477484#29477484